# Elements doesn't react to reactive props being changed

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

I have this code for a "Show Code", which will render the Code Snippet with different props based on the language selected by the user on the Code Header (working fine).
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCnKm.png)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <CodeHeader @language-selected="onLanguageSelected" />
        <CodeSnippet :language="selectedLanguage" :code="getCodeForLanguage(selectedLanguage)" />
        {{ selectedLanguage }} // WORKS
        {{ getCodeForLanguage(selectedLanguage)}} //WORKS

    </div>
</template>
            
<script>
import CodeSnippet from '@/components/atoms/CodeSnippet.vue';
import CodeHeader from '@/components/cells/CodeHeader.vue';

export default {
    name: 'ShowCode',
    components: {
        CodeSnippet,
        CodeHeader
    },
    data() {
        return {
            selectedLanguage: 'html', 
        };
    },
    methods: {
        onLanguageSelected(language) {
            language = language.toLowerCase();
            this.selectedLanguage = language;
        },
        getCodeForLanguage(language) {
            switch (language) {
                case 'html':
                    return '<h1>Oi</h1>';
                case 'css':
                    return '.h1 {}';
                case 'js':
                    return 'console.log(h1);';
                default:
                    return '';
            }
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

And this is my code snippet:

```
<template>
    <div class="code-snippet">
      <pre>
        <vue-prism-component :code="code" :language="language"> {{ code }} {{ language }}</vue-prism-component>
      </pre>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import VuePrismComponent from 'vue-prism-component';
  import 'prismjs/themes/prism.css';
  
  export default {
    name: 'CodeSnippet',
    components: {
      VuePrismComponent
    },
    props: {
      code: {
        type: String,
            default: 
            `<h1>Oops! No code found.</h1>\n <p>Sad :(</p>`
            
      },
      language: {
        type: String,
            default: 'html'
      }
    }
  };
  </script>
```

On the code you can see those works:

{{ selectedLanguage }} // WORKS
{{ getCodeForLanguage(selectedLanguage)}} //WORKS

But the Code Snippet doesn't change.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the Code Snippet" doesn't change? The code rendered by the Prism component?

Comment: Could you please include a [mre] so that we can more easily debug the code? You can use Vue in a Snippet, or use StackBlitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly valid, so I went digging.

Looking at the source code for `vue-prism-component`, I see that [props are read into regular variable](https://github.com/egoist/vue-prism-component/blob/v2.0.0/src/index.js#L24) which should kill their chance at reactivity or ever changing when used in the render function, as `setup` is run only once per component.

In fact, there's a [Github issue](https://github.com/egoist/vue-prism-component/issues/43) about that.

If you can, I suggest downgrading to `^1.0.0` until it's fixed.

Comment: I doubt it's going to be fixed. The maintainer has been inactive for three years.

Comment: I made a pull request fixing it, just in case

Comment: There is one, already, isn't there? From 2021.

Comment: Thank you. I found a work around it with a v-if, as I'm doing it only to learn Vue. That did the job.